# Nagios mongodb plugin python script unable to access pymongo

Tags: pip, pymongo, nagios

I have installed pymongo using pip and when I manually run the Nagios python plugin to check the status of my mongo servers, it is working properly. But when I try to run it via Nagios config file, the Nagios status says 
    No module named pymongo

Why may this be ?

I am running the Nagios on my local.

nagios command looks like this

```
define command {
    command_name    check_mongodb
    command_line    python /home/rishin/mongo1.py -H $HOSTADDRESS$ -A $ARG1$      -P $ARG2$ -W $ARG3$ -C $ARG4$
}
```

where mongo1.py is the plugin script

Answer (score 0):

Need some more information
1. Are you running nagios on the same mongo host?
2. Share your nagios defined command config.

Add #!/usr/bin/python2.7 to the  first line of the script if its not present and verify the result. Also check if you have multiple versions of python installed.

Regards,

Vady